# EclipseLink and Derby with Java 19

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, derby, java-19

This project used to work in Java 8 and NetBeans 8, but after upgrading my project to use Java 19 with NetBeans 16 I now see this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@c387f44
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.getName()" because "this.session" is null
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionSearchingForPersistenceResources(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:188)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at jdiskmark.EM.getEntityManager(EM.java:22)
    at jdiskmark.DiskRun.findAll(DiskRun.java:146)
    at jdiskmark.App.loadSavedRuns(App.java:219)
    at jdiskmark.App.init(App.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.getName()" because "this.session" is null
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2027)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.callPredeploy(JPAInitializer.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:104)
```

Here is the throwing line:

```java
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jDiskMarkPU");
em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

My persistence.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="jDiskMarkPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:derbyDB;create=true"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

javax.persistence_2.1.1v201509150925.jar

project source is here:
https://gitlab.com/jamesmarkchan/jDiskMark

I swapped in v4.0 of eclipselink.jar and that appears to resolve the null pointer thanks to hint from @Chris.

Currently seeing

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named jDiskMarkPU
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at jdiskmark.EM.getEntityManager(EM.java:22)
    at jdiskmark.DiskRun.findAll(DiskRun.java:146)
    at jdiskmark.App.loadSavedRuns(App.java:219)
    at jdiskmark.App.init(App.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
```

I'm not sure if I need to update my META-INF/persistence.xml definition or if the libraries need to be upgraded. In the EclipseLink 4.0.1 [download](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/rt/eclipselink/releases/4.0.1/eclipselink-4.0.1.v20230222-d91fc33f4c.zip) there are some libraries that I tried linking, but it did not resolve my PU issue.

The former libraries I had which I believe I need to replace

1. javax.persistence_2.1.1.v201509150925.jar
2. org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen_2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6.jar

These are the libraries I tried linking in place of them.

1. jakarta.annotation-api.jar
2. jakarta.persistence-api.jar
3. org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor.jar
4. org.eclipse.persistence.jpars.jar

But it seems that javax.persistence_2.1.1 is not substituted by the libraries provided by the EclipseLink package so I'm not sure which library I should use to replace it or am I mainly just needing to update my persistence.xml definition?

Comment: Maybe worth getting in touch with the author

Comment: Try EclipseLink version > 4.0 where they added Jakarta EE and JDK 11+17 support. You cannot just take a java 8 project and run in it on a JDK 19 as a lot has changed in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certain I did not need to but I did switch to jdk 21 w NetBeans 20 to take advantage of the current LTS release.

Libraries that needed to be updated for my legacy ant build:

- eclipselink.jar (v4.0)
- hibernate-jpamodelgen-jakarta-5.6.15.Final.jar
- jakarta.persistence-api-3.2.0-M1.jar
- jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.1.jar
- javax.annotation-3.1.2.2.jar

updated [persistence.xml](https://github.com/jDiskMark/jdm-java/blob/v0.5/src/META-INF/persistence.xml)

also class definitions have been relocated to jakarta.persistence

Answer (score 1):

I must thank u at the first, because I got the idea from your question. And in my case, I used Guice too. so,I modified Guice persist to adopt to jakarta and use these two dependences blow, then my problem is solved:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.persistence</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```